# How to check whether a jQuery selector is a unique id?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to check whether a given jQuery selector is for a unique identifier, not for a given set (class or html element).

```
$('#uniqueId') // Yes
$('p') // No
$('.class') // No
$('.class #uniqueId p') // No
```

**Edit:**
I want this, because I'm building a jQuery plugin that should work only with unique elements.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: you can check it by .each in jquery

Comment: Not what you are looking for, but you could always check if the `.length` is 1

Comment: Only the first one will ever be unique, because the rest can have more than 1 in your document. Apart from `$('body')` etc.

Answer (score 1):

[`$( selector ).length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) and [`$( selector ).size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/) should provide the number of elements matched by JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get that by checking the length of the selector like this:

```
if($(selector).length == 1){
    alert("yes");
}
```